# How do I set up a VPN, such that I can connect to my Samba Share and printer?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, vpn, samba, openvpn

I am looking for a way to set up my OpenVPN  server so that all my internet trafffic redirects through it, **and** I can access my Samba Share through it. My samba share is located on my server machine, which is a WIndows XP. Ideally, I should also be able to reach my printer. The hosts that may connect are iOS, Linux, Windows 7, and possibly Android.

Note: I would like to avoid dev tun as iOS doesn't support it.

OpenVPN configuration file:

> port 80
>
> proto udp
>
> :dev tap
>
> dev tun
>
> ;dev-node MyTap
>
> ca ca.crt
>
> cert xxx.crt
>
> key xxx.key
>
> dh dh2048.pem
>
> ;topology subnet
>
> server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>
> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
>
> ;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100
>
> ;server-bridge
>
> ;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
>
> ;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
>
> ;client-config-dir ccd
>
> ;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
>
> ;client-config-dir ccd
>
> ;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
>
> ;learn-address ./script
>
> ;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
>
> push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
>
> push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
>
> client-to-client
>
> keepalive 10 120
>
> tls-auth ta.key 0
>
> cipher AES-256-CBC
>
> comp-lzo
>
> ;max-clients 100
>
> persist-key
>
> persist-tun
>
> verb 3
>
> ;mute 20

Comment: Looks like you've got a good start with OpenVPN.  What specific problems are you having with that configuration?  Do you have the server installed?  Do you have the keys setup?  Do you have the client installed and configured?  Can the clients connect? Please provide more details.

Comment: Keys are setup. Clients are configured, and the server is installed. Everything works okay on the server. I'll do further testing later.

Comment: why and how are you having a samba share on windows?! AFAIK Windows uses SMB.. and Linux uses Samba.. Samba AFAIK is for linux systems to simulate windows file sharing.

Comment: @barlop Oh, I was transferring my network drive from my router, and I must have gotten the names mixed up.

Comment: I have done  a VPN on Win7. I think you get an IP from that network you connect to. And so if at the end where the VPN server is, you have a some windows file sharing servers set up, or linux samba servers set up, and computers on your LAN can access it, then the computer you connect remotely should be able to access it. It's effectively on your LAN. You should find you can ping and access any servers.